# SharePoint Store: Sorry, something went wrong

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

Today, I have been trying to install a **SharePoint Add-in** into my SharePoint O365 site from the SharePoint store and the following error message was displayed:

[image]

Then, I went to my System Admin and followed the same steps to replicate the issue (I even logged in with my credentials), but the app got installed successfully.

This was quite strange. I have never thought that the functionality of SharePoint O365 is dependent on machine to machine.

Can anyone please tell me a resolution to it?

Btw, FYI:  I am having SharePoint Admin privilege and also I am an SCA to that Site Collection and both the machines were connected to the same Internet Network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this happens, then a ticket has to be raised to Microsoft. They said that there was a problem at the backend and has been resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

Not only **Add-in** even sometimes, while adding **site pages** also shows that error message,I think this may be an online issue so try to logout and close the browser and open it and login. It worked me for sometimes. But it is **not** a exact solution.